# Getting started with pylons on a VPS with Apache

Tags: python, apache, pylons, pyramid

I currently have Apache setup on my VPS and I'm wondering what would be the best way to handle Pylons development.

I have the directory structure with `public_html` in my home directory which includes separate website directories to which I map the IP to the DNS provided by my name registrar.

Is there a way to get paster running within a new directory (i.e. make an env/bin/paster) and run it to that?

If so then do I even need to get a new IP? Or would I be able to run both webservers in parallel on the same server without experiencing any conflicts?

I'm looking to convert all my new projects to Pylons.

Comment: Pylons is now a project where Pyramid is the main project. Are you referring to the old Pylons, Pylons 1.0 or Pyramid?

Answer (score 1):

It's usually more practical to develop first your application locally using `pserve`, the builtin HTTP server in Pyramid (it used to be paster before Pyramid 1.3 but pserve behaves similarly). This HTTP server comes quite handy when developing for debugging, but you don't usually expose your web application publicly with this server.

Once your application is ready to go public you should *deploy* your application on your server with another HTTP server like Apache. You can use `WSGIScriptAlias` if you have Apache with mod_wsgi, [as it's documented](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/vhosting.html#virtual-root-support) in Pyramid, to map a subdirectory.

The official [documentation explains](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/vhosting.html#virtual-root-support) also explains how you can have different subdirectories running different Pyramid instances with a virtual root.

If you really want to make your application accessible publicly with `pserve`, you can still use the `urlmap` [composite functionality](http://pythonpaste.org/deploy/#composite-applications) of PasteDeploy [as explained in the documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/vhosting.html#hosting-an-application-under-a-url-prefix).

If your DNS are properly configured you don't need to mess with the IP.